# Convert $http request to Restangular

Tags: angularjs, http, restangular

I'm trying to use [Angular-UI Bootstrap Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to search names from remote server.

Input search field is implemented as follows.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="selectedName" typeahead="name for name in search($viewValue)" class="form-control">
```

And equivalent controller code is as follows.

```
 $scope.search = function (term) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'names/search.json',
                    params: {
                        q: term
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    var names = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        names.push(response.data[i]);
                    }
                    return names;
                });
            };
```

Currently, it is working fine by using `$http`

I'm trying to use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) for server communication.

I've tried changing above controller code as follows but it doesn't work.

```
$scope.search = function(term) {
                return Restangular.all('users').one('search').getList({q:term}).then(
                    function(names) {
                        return names.plain();
                    }
                )      
            };
```

With above implementation, response from server is fine as expect but `[object Object]` is shown in dropdown instead of names.

How can I convert above `$http` request to use `Restangular`?

Comment: Angular-UI Bootstrap Typeahead link is not opening.

Comment: @Prashant Fixed the link. But TypeAhead directive will have to searched manually.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced promises -

> $object: This returns the reference to the object that will be filled
>   once the server responds a value. This means that if you call getList
>   this will be an empty array by default. Once the array is returned
>   from the server, this same $object property will get filled with
>   results from the server.

```
Restangular.all("filter").getList().$object
```

Comment: No need for the .then() part...and keep it simple...it's a promise...don't make the function return anything...just set it to a scope variable and use it in ng-model.

Comment: Setting in ng-model is what I normally do but `typeahead` depends on promises as in its example.